# Angular 4 HttpClientModule and map() function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am facing an issue in regard to new `HttpClientModule` and the `map()` function from RX.js.

What I want to do is to change the objects of the returned array inside the observable coming from the `get()` method.

My curent code:

```js
get(url: string): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.get(this.config.baseUrl + url);
}


playerSearch(text: string): Observable < any[] > {
  if (text == "" || !text) {
    return Observable.of([]);
  } else {
    return this.auth.get(`/players?$expand=Contact($expand=Blob)&$filter=contains(Contact/LastName, '${text}') or contains(Contact/FirstName, '${text}')`).map((x) => {
      return {
        Id: x.Id,
        Name: x.Contact.FirstName + " " + x.Contact.FatherName.substring(0, 2) + ". " + x.Contact.LastName,
        BlobSrc: this.utilitiesService.imageLinkCreator(x)
      }
    });
  }
}

search = (text$: Observable < string > ) =>
  text$
  .debounceTime(300)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .do(() => this.searching = true)
  .switchMap(term =>
    this.dataService.playerSearch(term)
    .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
    .catch(() => {
      this.searchFailed = true;
      return Observable.of([]);
    }))
  .do(() => this.searching = false);
```

The error that I get:

> Type 'Observable<{ Id: any; Name: string; BlobSrc: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>
> Type '{ Id: any; Name: string; BlobSrc: string; }' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

As far as I know, the `map()` method returns an `observable` with value only one object instead of an array.

What is the correct syntax in order to return an observable containing an Array of `{ Id: any; Name: string; BlobSrc: string; }` objects?

Comment: What do you expect to be returned from the http request?

Comment: Actually `map` doesn't have anything to do with arrays/not arrays, it only takes an `Observable<T>` and a function `T => S` and returns an `Observable<S>`

Comment: In this case you marked your return value as `Observable<any[]>` which is first of all an array, but you map your data into an object.

Answer (score 0):

If your http request returns an array of players, then this is how your code should look like:

```
get(url: string): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.config.baseUrl + url);
    }


playerSearch(text: string): Observable<any[]> {
    if (text == "" || !text) {
        return Observable.of([]);
    } else {
        return this.auth.get(`/players?$expand=Contact($expand=Blob)&$filter=contains(Contact/LastName, '${text}') or contains(Contact/FirstName, '${text}')`).map((arr: any[]) => {
            return arr.map(x => ({
                Id: x.Id,
                Name: x.Contact.FirstName + " " + x.Contact.FatherName.substring(0, 2) + ". " + x.Contact.LastName,
                BlobSrc: this.utilitiesService.imageLinkCreator(x)
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes Amit the http req returns an array of players. I used your code but it seems that `return arr.map`  not working

Comment: I have posted the code that I try to run above Amit.

Answer (score 0):

```
playerSearch(text: string): Observable<any[]> {
    if (text == "" || !text) {
        return Observable.of([]);
    } else {
        return this.auth.get(`/players?$expand=Contact($expand=Blob)&$filter=contains(Contact/LastName, '${text}') or contains(Contact/FirstName, '${text}')`)
            .map((arr: any[]) => {
                return arr.map(x => {
                    debugger;
                    ({
                        Id: x.Id,
                        Name: x.Contact.FirstName + " " + x.Contact.FatherName.substring(0, 2) + ". " + x.Contact.LastName,
                        BlobSrc: this.utilitiesService.imageLinkCreator(x)
                    })
                });
            });
    }
}
```

Here is the code I try to run, based on yours Amit. I add a debugger inside nested `map` but never get in. There is no actual error.